# Is it possible to write a data type Converter to handle postgres JSON columns?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Ideally using Jackson on the Java side of things. I have tried the obvious solution:

```
public class JsonObjectConverter implements Converter<Object, ObjectNode> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override public ObjectNode from(Object dbo) {
        try {
            return dbo != null ? mapper.readValue((String) dbo, ObjectNode.class) : null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override public Object to(ObjectNode uo) {
        try {
            return uo != null ? mapper.writeValueAsString(uo) : null;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override public Class<Object> fromType() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override public Class<ObjectNode> toType() {
        return ObjectNode.class;
    }
}
```

But if I try to use this I get errors like the following:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."my_table" ("id", "stuff") values (?, ?)]; ERROR: column "stuff" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

However because of jOOQs enforced type safety (which is great, BTW) I can't just add a `.cast(String.class)` and be done. So, do I need to do something else in the converter, or should the code be called in a different way? I'm currently doing this:

```
Long id = ...
ObjectNode stuff = ...
create.insertInto(MY_TABLE)
    .set(MY_TABLE.ID, id)
    .set(MY_TABLE.STUFF, stuff)
    .execute();
```

and am using updatable records in other places in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't get the JSON data type 100% correct with a `Converter` only. Ideally, you should use a jOOQ 3.5 [`org.jooq.Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Binding.html) implementation, which is documented here:

- [How to insert a updatable record with JSON column in PostgreSQL using JOOQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27044702/521799)
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

The code generator can be configured to use your custom `Binding` (instead or in addition to `Converters`) directly on your database columns. The `Binding` will then take care of all necessary interaction on a JDBC level.

Comment: Yup, upgrading to 3.5 is on my todo list.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is, but you need to use Postgres specific API. In the code above you need to replace the from/to methods with the following:

```
@Override
public ObjectNode from(Object databaseObject) {
    if (databaseObject == null) { return null; }
    try {
        PGobject dbo = (PGobject) databaseObject;
        return mapper.readValue(dbo.getValue(), ObjectNode.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public Object to(ObjectNode userObject) {
    if (userObject == null) { return null; }
    try {
        PGobject dbo = new PGobject();
        dbo.setType("json");
        dbo.setValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(userObject));
        return dbo;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException|SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```