# How to insert a updatable record with JSON column in PostgreSQL using JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, jooq

I followed the answer in [Is it possible to write a data type Converter to handle postgres JSON columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685605/is-it-possible-to-write-a-data-type-converter-to-handle-postgres-json-columns/25686858#25686858)
 to implement the nodeObject converter.

Then I tried to use an updatable record to insert a record, I got *"org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class org.postgresql.util.PGobject is not supported in dialect POSTGRES" exception."*

How can I solve this?

Following is my code:

```
TableRecord r = create.newRecord(TABLE);
ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
r.setValue(TABLE.JSON_FIELD, node, new JsonObjectConverter());
r.store();
```

Comment: Prior to jOOQ 3.5 (just released), PostgreSQL's JSON type was quite hard to integrate with jOOQ. We've now changed that. [Some preliminary information can be seen here on this user group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/nThHA-yFrMU/MF6BqcyXpLsJ). We'll be updating manuals, etc. soon and I'll answer this question with details. Just to be sure, you are using Jackson, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using Jackson.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Current jOOQ versions

jOOQ has native support for `JSON` and `JSONB` data types, so you don't have to do anything specific.

#### Historic answer

Since jOOQ 3.5, you can register your own custom data type bindings to the code generator as is documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

Unlike a [`Converter`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Converter.html), a [`Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Binding.html) dictates how your data type is being handled at the JDBC level within jOOQ, without jOOQ knowing about your implementation. I.e., not only will you define how to convert between `<T>` and `<U>` types (`T` = database type, `U` = user type), but you will also be able to define how such types are:

- Rendered as SQL
- Bound to PreparedStatements
- Bound to SQLOutput
- Registered in CallableStatements as OUT parameters
- Fetched from ResultSets
- Fetched from SQLInput
- Fetched from CallableStatements as OUT parameters

An example `Binding` for use with Jackson to produce `JsonNode` types is given here:

```
public class PostgresJSONJacksonJsonNodeBinding 
implements Binding<Object, JsonNode> {

    @Override
    public Converter<Object, JsonNode> converter() {
        return new PostgresJSONJacksonJsonNodeConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<JsonNode> ctx) throws SQLException {

        // This ::json cast is explicitly needed by PostgreSQL:
        ctx.render().visit(DSL.val(ctx.convert(converter()).value())).sql("::json");
    }

    @Override
    public void register(BindingRegisterContext<JsonNode> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<JsonNode> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.statement().setString(
            ctx.index(), 
            Objects.toString(ctx.convert(converter()).value()));
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<JsonNode> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index()));
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<JsonNode> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()));
    }

    // The below methods aren't needed in PostgreSQL:

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<JsonNode> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<JsonNode> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And the `Converter` that is used above can be seen here:

```
public class PostgresJSONJacksonJsonNodeConverter 
implements Converter<Object, JsonNode> {
    @Override
    public JsonNode from(Object t) {
        try {
            return t == null 
              ? NullNode.instance 
              : new ObjectMapper().readTree(t + "");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object to(JsonNode u) {
        try {
            return u == null || u.equals(NullNode.instance) 
              ? null 
              : new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(u);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object> fromType() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<JsonNode> toType() {
        return JsonNode.class;
    }
}
```

You can now register the above binding via the code generator configuration:

```
<customType>
    <name>com.example.PostgresJSONJacksonJsonNodeBinding</name>
    <type>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode</type>
    <binding>com.example.PostgresJSONJacksonJsonNodeBinding</binding>
</customType>

<forcedType>
    <name>com.example.PostgresJSONJacksonJsonNodeBinding</name>
    <expression>my_schema\.table\.json_field</expression>
</forcedType>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas!  Your solution and v3.5 comes at a perfect time!

Comment: @Lukas, what if we do not know the target type, we want to bind any JSON object to whatever we happen to have as the result type object?  All of the examples for converters, type binding is specific `DB-Type => User-Type` and not `DB-Type => ?` (all postgres objects to whatever we want at the moment)

Comment: @JaysonMinard: Hard to say. I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. Perhaps you could ask a new question on Stack Overflow or on the [user group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user) with some explanations? I'll be very happy to answer then.

Comment: @LukasEder I am not using an autogenerated code, and I need GSON what can I do?

Comment: @nairavs: Ask a new question :)

Comment: @LukasEder done, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595910/issue-with-jooq-json-binding