# Update hstore fields using jooq

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq, hstore

Does anybody know is it possible to update value by key in **hstore** using JOOQ, except executing plain sql.
For example, I have table **products**

```
 id |                                  characs                                   |         name         
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------
  1 | "key"=>"value", "key3"=>"test2"                                            | test1    
  2 | "key"=>"value"                                                             | test3               
  3 | "keyNew"=>"valueNew"                                                       | test3               
  4 | "keyNew"=>"valueNew"                                                       | test4               
  5 | "date"=>"Dec 2012", "price"=>"500", "author"=>"Dave", "currency"=>"dollar" | test5
```

And I want to update value by key **key3**. For that I can execute plain sql:

```
UPDATE products SET name='test1New', characs=characs || '"key3"=>"value3"'::hstore where id=1
```

Is it possible to do using JOOQ's **DSL**?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible, but not yet supported out-of-the box. In order to implement your own HSTORE support, you will need to:

#### 1. Implement an [`org.jooq.Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Binding.html)

This binding will be used for all HSTORE columns in your database. It will take care of handling the interaction of your user type `<U>` (e.g. `Map<String, String>`) with JDBC, in order to produce a database type `<T>` (e.g. `String`, or `PGobject`).

An example of how to do this with the `JSON` type can be seen here:

- [How to insert a updatable record with JSON column in PostgreSQL using JOOQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27044702/521799)
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/

The `HSTORE` type will work roughly the same way

#### 2. Implement your own operators via plain SQL

PostgreSQL has a lot of vendor-specific operators that go with the vendor-specific data types. These operators will need to be implemented via plain SQL. For instance:

```java
public class DSLExtensions {
    public static Field<String> get(
            Field<Map<String, String>> hstore, String key) {
        return DSL.field("{0} -> {1}", String.class, hstore, DSL.val(key));
    }

    public static Field<String[]> get(
            Field<Map<String, String>> hstore, String[] keys) {
        return DSL.field("{0} -> {1}", String[].class, hstore, DSL.val(keys));
    }

    public static Field<Map<String, String>> concat(
            Field<Map<String, String>> f1,
            Field<Map<String, String>> f2) {
        return DSL.field("{0} || {1}", f1.getDataType(), f1, f2);
    }

    // etc...
}
```