# Issue with JOOQ json binding

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have an issue with converting postgresql jsonb 
I created Binding as was explained in tutorial : [jooq tutorial](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/)
Also please note I am not using codegen
In my repo I have the following code

```
Binding binding = new PostgresJSONGsonBinding();
Field<JsonElement> gsonObj = 
       DSL.field("gsonObj",SQLDataType.OTHER.asConvertedDataType(binding));
```

And getting an error in to and from methods

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 42 path $.factories[1]
```

Can someone help to understand what I am doing wrong

And yes I saw other questions : [issue with jooq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044702/how-to-insert-a-updatable-record-with-json-column-in-postgresql-using-jooq/27146852?noredirect=1#comment97886779_27146852)

Comment: Can you please show how you're using that field in a jOOQ query, as well as what the data in `gsonObj` looks like?

Comment: It already work , the issue was with JsonElement , now I have issue with timestamp , I am using postgresql and have timestamp with timezon , I implemented reccord mapper but getting Caused by: org.jooq.exception.MappingException: No matching constructor found . , shoud I open new question? :) @LukasEder

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question here, as that might be useful for someone else in the future, and then yes, please ask a new question about your new issue.

Comment: yes sure , added .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working code**

```
public class PostgresJSONGsonBinding implements Binding<Object, JsonElement> {
    // Binding <T> = Object (unknown JDBC type), and <U> = JsonElement (user type)

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostgresJSONGsonBinding.class);

    // The converter does all the work
    @Override
    public Converter<Object, JsonElement> converter() {
        return new Converter<Object, JsonElement>() {

            //Convert a database object to a user object
            @Override
            public JsonElement from(Object t) {
                return t == null ? JsonNull.INSTANCE : new Gson().fromJson(t.toString(), JsonElement.class);
            }

            // Convert a user object to a database object
            @Override
            public Object to(JsonElement u) {
                return u == null || u == JsonNull.INSTANCE ? null : new Gson().toJson(u);
            }

            @Override
            public Class<Object> fromType() {
                return Object.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<JsonElement> toType() {
                return JsonElement.class;
            }
        };
    }

    // Rending a bind variable for the binding context's value and casting it to the json type
    @Override
    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // Depending on how you generate your SQL, you may need to explicitly distinguish
        // between jOOQ generating bind variables or inlined literals.
        if (ctx.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED){
            ctx.render().visit(DSL.inline(ctx.convert(converter()).value())).sql("::json");
        }
        else{
            ctx.render().sql("?::json");
        }
    }

    // Registering VARCHAR types for JDBC CallableStatement OUT parameters
    @Override
    public void register(BindingRegisterContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR);
    }

    // Converting the JsonElement to a String value and setting that on a JDBC PreparedStatement
    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.statement().setString(ctx.index(), Objects.toString(ctx.convert(converter()).value(), null));
    }

    // Getting a String value from a JDBC ResultSet and converting that to a JsonElement
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index()));
    }

    // Getting a String value from a JDBC CallableStatement and converting that to a JsonElement
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()));
    }

    // Setting a value on a JDBC SQLOutput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    // Getting a value from a JDBC SQLInput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }
}
```